# what is the default internal clock for pic16f1946?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, oscillator, timer

While going through the [data sheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41414C.pdf), section 5.3.1 says: "Default system oscillator determined by FOSC bits in Configuration Word 1". How can find the value of this default clock, is it 8MHz or 31khz?

I am trying to generate a 10 msec delay and i am using 31khz in my calculations, but i think it is not right.

TMR0_Load_val * 4/Fosc = delay
TMR0_Load_val = 10msec * Fosc / 4 
= 78.

Thank  you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default oscillator frequency after a reset is 500 kHz. See Section 5.2.2.5 for details of how to change the frequency.